# Word order when answering questions with 有

Tags: translation, grammar, usage, word

Please correct my word order and explain 有-usage rules.

Question:

> 哪里有中国地图？

The task for me is to translate the answer, using 有. My variant is:

> 他哪里有中国地图。

Is it possible to say:

> 那里他有中国地图。(There, with him there is the Chinese map.)

The same problem, with

> 哪儿有市场？

And my variant of the answer is:

> 公园这儿有市场。(Here, with park there is a market).

Comment: I'm sorry, you need to translate the answer? What does that mean?

Comment: Hello, yes. I have translated the answers, but am not sure in word order.

Comment: `哪里有中国地图?` is fine.  `他哪里有中国地图。` is fine also. `公园这儿有市场` is okay if you are at the park when you say this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Locations should use 在:

市场在哪儿？ / 市场在公园里。

Likewise, a means for obtaining something is sometimes required:

中国地图哪儿买的？ / 中国地图在那家书店买的。

去哪儿找中国地图？ / 可以在图书馆找到中国地图。

Comment: Thank you! Yes, I know about 在 usage, but the task in the excercise was to answer the questions using 有 in meaning (there is/there are). And with 有 usage sometimes I don't know which word order will be correct.

Comment: Usually, 有 means more permanent existence, like in 东边有海，北边有山，西边有个琥珀，庙里有个姑娘。As for word order, Mandarin prefers SVO: 他有个女朋友。 Location is normally placed between subject and verb: 他 (subject) 在天津 (location) 有 (verb) 个 (classifier) 女朋友 (object). Location can be placed more freely, though: 在天津 (location) 他 (subject) 有 (verb) 个 (classifier) 虐朋友 (object), or 他有个女朋友在天津。

Answer (score 1):

Q: 哪里有中国地图？

A1: 他那里有中国地图。
A2: 他那儿有中国地图。

Normally, "哪里" is for question, we could use "那里" to answer the location of something.

那里他有中国地图： Incorrect order for "那里" and "他", "他那里" is fine.

有-Usage rules in your case is pretty straight forward, it normally put in-front of the object that you are mention. But for some cases, you could let your sentence starts with 有, for example, 有个中国地图在他那里 (There is a Chinese map with him.)